# iOS, Swift -How disable a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm currently working on an App that uses Parse as backend system. I would like to implement a "Liking" feature. Here's my code

```
 @IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Content")

    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(object.objectId, block: { (obj:PFObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in


        if error != nil{
            println("Update error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }else{

            var likesNumber = obj.objectForKey("Likes")[0] as Int
            obj["Likes"] = [likesNumber + 1]

            self.likeslab.setTitle("\(likesNumber + 1) likes", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.likesButton.enabled = false

            obj.save()


            }


    })


}
```

The code works well unfortunately, I've a problem: after a user touch on the button I would like to disable it (in order to avoid multiples likes from a same user). I try do that on the following line:

```
 self.likesButton.enabled = false
```

And It's working but if the user leave the view and then go back, the button is enabled again.
Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that has to be provided on the server side. The server has to give you the information whether the user has liked something or not. Then you can set `enabled` in `viewWillAppear:` method on the controller.

There are some things in your code that smell really bad, for example this:

```
var likesNumber = obj.objectForKey("Likes")[0] as Int
obj["Likes"] = [likesNumber + 1]
```

It seems that instead of incrementing the number of likes on the server, you are doing it on the client. There are many reasons why this won't work like you expect it to work.

What you need is a database on the server that will track which user has liked what. You don't want to save just the number of likes, you want to save the list of users who did like the object.

Comment: He could also save it in NSUserDefaults as a boolean, than set the button based on that.

Comment: @Michael What if you log in as the same user from a different device? What if the user uninstalls the app and then installs again? All the data on the devices can be lost and it's much better to save it on the server side. It's just too easy to get into a state where data saved on the client and data saved on the server are not in sync. You could do it this way but it is a pain to do and once the user moves to a different device, their data is lost.

Comment: By the way, likes are usually implemented for two reasons: 1. to offer similar products to the user 2. to offer proper advertising. For both reasons you need to know who liked on the server. Not the number of likes.

Comment: You get completely right I will try to do that on the server side. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should have to take in some way memory of your button disabled.

One example is to add a flag, in your ViewController, which is updated when you disable or enable your UIButton. So when you update your button with `self.likesButton.enabled = false`, you change your flag value to false.

Then in `ViewWillAppear` you add these lines:

```
if flag { self.likesButton.enabled = true } else { self.likesButton.enabled = false }
```

Obviously that your flag variable should be added as class variable.

Hope that this helps you.

Here's the code that I'd add, for you as beginner:

```
var isButtonEnabled:Bool = true


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

           self.isButtonEnabled = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("isButtonEnabled")

    if(isButtonEnabled){

       self.likesButton.enabled = true
    }
    else{
       self.likesButton.enabled = false
    }

}

@IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

var query = PFQuery(className: "Content")

query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(object.objectId, block: { (obj:PFObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in


    if error != nil{
        println("Update error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }else{

        var likesNumber = obj.objectForKey("Likes")[0] as Int
        obj["Likes"] = [likesNumber + 1]

        self.likeslab.setTitle("\(likesNumber + 1) likes", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.likesButton.enabled = false

        obj.save()


        }

   self.likesButton.enabled = false
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(false, forKey: "isButtonEnabled")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
 })
```

}

Comment: Ever heard about View-Model-Controller pattern? Never ever save data on controllers. Save data on the model.

Comment: It's a fast way to save it, it's a common flag. My answer works, it's not right to add a -1 for my answer.

Comment: No, it won't really work. Will it work when you restart the app? What if you just open a different object? Of course, there are no "class variables" in obj-c either but I suppose you meant using a singleton pattern using class methods and static (file) variable.

Comment: I know it, but the question was How disable a UIButton, right?! He didn't say to make a persistent store to make disabled or enabled an UIButton. read the question. I provided an answer to his question. If He wanted to make it persistent, so he should need to save it on server side instead of client side.

Comment: Now In my code you save it in StandardUserDefaults, this is the fastest persistent way to save it in your app (client side).

Comment: Bellots thanks a lot for your time and your help but I think that just like you and Sulthan said it's safer to do that on the server side.

Comment: Unfortunately I've not enough reputation to upvote but your answer is in adequacy with my question

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

```
btnEnviar.isEnabled = false
```

or

```
btnEnviar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```